# Live code following document ready in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I currently have a basic site to which I am loading content into via ajax on document ready. The problem is that this code is not "live" and requires me to re-include the php includes within the loaded page in order to access the queries contained within it.

I know you can work around this by using the 'on' method when it comes to certain events so that the dynamically loaded code is functional from the start, but how would you go about it when the page has just loaded? It seems redundant and sloppy to have to reinclude my php includes on each loaded page.

Here's some code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('dbconnect.php');
    require_once('functions.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="x.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div id="content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').load('x.php', function() {
        alert("loaded");
    });
});
```

Loaded page:

```
<?php
    //LOAD ALL WORK
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM work");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        while ($work = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
?>

<div class="still_cell">
    <img class="still_image" src="<?php 
        print $work['image_path'];
    ?>" />

    <div class="still_info">
        Info
    </div>
</div>

<?php   
        }
    }
?>
```

Results in various php errors saying that the query produced no results unless I include the code to connect to the database nested in the loaded file

Comment: Can you include some code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is unaware of what the client does.
When the browser makes an AJAX call, this appears as an independent request to the web server.
The key point is, that PHP is independently executed for each incomming request.

There are ways to persist data between multiple requests to PHP, like:

- APC (PHP extension): originally a cache for compiled PHP scripts - can also store user data in memory which persists between requests.
- Files: Serialize variables and store them in a file.

However, when it comes to something like resources (MySQL connection, file handles, etc.), it is considered *unsafe* to try to persist them. APC and serialization for instance will refuse to work with a resource type.

The conclusion: bootstrapping (connecting to DB, declaring classes, functions etc.) is usually done **for each request**.

Answer (score 2):

you need put the

```
require_once('dbconnect.php');
require_once('functions.php');
```

in your page which you are trying into the #content.

regardless of where you call the page, the page you are calling is a separate page, so without any reference it don't have the connectivity to the database.

php is CGI so all the php code is exicuted at server before sending the page to the browser,
so you need to provide reference to the connection files as well as all other files to make the database connectivity work in the other page.